# Firefox extension observing response

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying using code

```js
// This is an active module of the goelvivek (8) Add-on
exports.main = function() {
  var httpRequestObserver =  
  {  
    observe: function(subject, topic, data)   
    { 
      if (topic == "http-on-examine-response") {  
        if(console)
          console.log(data);
      }  
    }  
  }; 
  var {Cc, Ci, Cr} = require("chrome");
  var observer = require("observer-service");   
  observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].  
    getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);  
    observerService.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-examine-response", false);
};
```

but line `console.log(data);` is not printing any thing in console log. why ?

Comment: did you get the data with below solution. If so can you please update the above code because i tried pasting the same code in main.js with below modifications but i am not getting anything in console.log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the issue noted by Nickolay, an observer needs to implement a `QueryInterface()` function (typically by means of [XPCOMUtils.generateQI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm#generateQI%28%29)). Here is how one would do it with the Add-on SDK:

```js
var {Cc, Ci, Cr, Cu} = require("chrome");
var {XPCOMUtils} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
var httpRequestObserver =
{
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIObserver, Ci.nsISupportsWeakReference]),
  ...
};
```

However, since you already require [`observer-service` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/packages/api-utils/docs/observer-service.html), it would be easier to use it:

```js
var observer = require("observer-service");
observer.add("http-on-examine-response", onHttpRequest);

function onHttpRequest(subject, data)
{
  ...
}
```

The downside of this approach is that `observer-service` is an internal package and its API might change in future Add-on SDK versions.

Comment: I tried the above example with including your code but i am not getting the output.

Comment: @user1275375: Feel free to check the Error Console, rather than stating "no output". The code here works correctly in the context of an Add-on SDK module. You probably run it in a content script or some other context that it isn't meant for.

Comment: I just created a new Add-on in add-on builder and included this code in main.js. As for errors i didn't find any in error console.

Comment: @user1275375: Feel free to create a new question then, along with your code.

Comment: But creating the same question as new can become duplicate. i just pasted the same code presented here and included the variables in the solution provided. am i doing anything wrong

Comment: @user1275375: You are correct there. I guess that SO is the wrong place to help you with your debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the real snippet? You should see an error about `Components` being undefined in the Error Console. Either get it from `require('chrome')` or use the object from `require("observer-service")`.

Comment: Actually, a better advice would probably be to use `Cc` instead of `Components.classes` and `Ci` instead of `Components.interfaces` since these variables *are* defined.